WP form in footer widget is not displaying
I am beginner with WP and I am about to build my first site using Ocena WP theme but I came accross an issue with Footer widget, I created newsletter form in WP forms and then added it as a widget and as you can see it does not display, any suggestion is welcome, thanks a lot!
I tried to change it in customization->widgets and play with the options I found there but no success

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
